# DDD: DTOs and Parameter Objects

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm modeling my domain using DDD/CQRS and I have a problem with naming things.

Assume that I have a Category aggregate that is a tree-like structure and I want to update the category tree:

```java
class CategoryItemEntity {
    Long guid;
    String title;
    List<CategoryItem> children;
    Datetime createdAt;
    Datetime updatedAt;
}

class CategoryItemParameterObject {
    Long guid;
    String title;
    List<CategoryItem> children;
}

class CategoryAggregate {
     Long guid;
     List<CategoryItem> items;

     void updateTree(List<CategoryItemParameterObject> items) {
          // ...
     }
}
```

My question is What should I call `CategoryItemParameterObject`? Is it a DTO or Something else? I also have a `CategoryItemDTO` on my read side. If I call it `CategoryItemDTO` would it make that confusing?

Is it ok to send commands directly to aggregates?

Comment: I think its a matter of taste but I personally name them after their usage. I would call the `CategoryItemParameterObject` `UpdatedCategoryItem` or `NewCategoryItem` depending on whether it is used for update or create operations and put them in a separate `Arguments` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a command? An entity?
Just thing about it's use and add to it a suffix/prefix that gives to who reads the code (not you, but **who will do it 3, 6 or 12 months later**) useful information about it's possible usage.
About the second question: yes, there's no rule that denies this. If the entity could handle the command itself, do it. I have an handler for a command that takes it, loads the entity and give the command to it. It works flawless and the meaning is really clear. Again, think about who will maintain the code, later, and do the thing that requires less thinking 'hops'.